# Is There a Shorter Way of Saying/Word for "Person who gave birth to you"?

Tags: abbreviations

When you're born and given up for adoption, what do you call the person who gave birth to you? I do not like the phrase "Birthmom" or "Birthparent" or anything like that since the person who gave birth to me is not actually my mom. She didn't raise me, so I would like a shorter way of saying this or a certain word for this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, the only other phrase that I know of is "birth mother". You can get a hair more clinical if donor eggs were involved, but that simply makes things more awkward.

Comment: *biological mother* (but that does not imply that she gave birth to you)

Answer (score 4):

As opposed to your adoptive parents, the people who actually gave you life in legal speak are called your [biological parents](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/biological_parent) (or sometimes your [natural parents](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/natural+parent)). So, to refer to your real mom, you would say my biological mother and to refer to your real dad, you would say my biological father.

Comment: I like the answer except for the "real". Adoptive parents (or any other type) as much real ac biological ones. Real parent is whoever the child feels like they are.

Answer (score 0):

If the OP wants to avoid using the most common and easily understood terms 1. *biological mother* and 2. *birth mother*, I suppose they could describe their parent, rather icily, as their

> **hominid host**

[hominid](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hominid)
adjective
2. of, relating to, or belonging to the Hominidae

- *Any of various primates of the family Hominidae, whose only living members are modern humans.*

Source: *Dictionary.com*

Comment: I think terms like this may come across as not just cold but potentially offensive.

Comment: +1 because this term applies to either (1) the genetic mother (gm), whose egg was fertilized by the genetic father, and who carried the fetus and gave birth to the child or (2) a non-genetic mother who received the fertilized egg from the gm and then carried the fetus and gave birth to the child. (Sometimes called surrogate mother.)  It does not cover the practice in The Vor science fiction series by Lois McMaster Bujold where a fertilized egg is put in a uterine replicator; the genetic parents are usually present at the decanting of the child,  unless they are exceptionally squeamish.